# Как запустить скрипт Python после полной загрузки Linux?

Tags: python, linux, автозапуск

Здравствуйте.
Написал скрипт на Python, для работы с сокетами, отладил, проверил - все работает идеально.
Теперь необходимо повесить его на автозагрузку в Linux. В Windows я понимаю как сделать: добавить в реестр (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Run) запись с командой, или же поместить ярлык команды в папку Автозагрузка. Пробовал добавить в cron (@reboot <команда> &), но не работает. В rc.local строку с командой - не работает. Команда:

```
/usr/bin/Python3.5 <путь к скрипту>
```

А как сделать то же самое в Linux? Интересует решение для Linux Mint или подобных.

Comment: *"Не работает"* это не очень информативно. Как @reboot в cron так и `rc.local` работают для обычных команд (окружение может отличаться). Как сервисы запускать зависит что используется на конкретном дистрибутиве (systemd, upstart, init.d SysV скрипты итд).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создается скрипт в папке /etc/init.d

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/<name_this_script>.script //где nano - это консольный текстовый редактор. На его месте может быть любой другой.
```

Пишем скрипт. Содержание следующее:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/bin/Python3.5 <путь_к_Вашему_скрипту> > /dev/null & start
```

Разрешаем файлу выполняться созданному скрипту:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/<name_this_script>.script
```

Добавляем созданный скрипт в автозагрузку:

```
sudo update-rc.d <name_this_script>.script defaults 95 //95-это порядок загрузки скрипта. Чем больше число - тем позже он загрузится.
```

Перегружаемся:

```
reboot
```

Если нужно удалить скрипт из автозагрузки, тогда:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f <name_this_script>.script remove
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все так, как нужно.

Comment: В минте вроде как systemd вместо всего этого, или ещё нет?

Comment: А как потом перезапустить скрипт? > start: not found